# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql

My friend set up a server at home, and he gave me the server address (example.dyndns.org)
I wanted to connect from VisualStudio, but i cant

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection mc = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=example.dyndns.org;port=3306;UID=example;DATABASE=test;password=example");

            mc.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("OH YEAH");
        }
    }
}
```

in the browser the link(example.dyndns.org) worked, but in the program i can't connect.

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Is port 3306 open on his firewall? What aboubt port forwarding? Was it set?

Comment: ohhh, port forwarding !! that was the problem :D thanks for helping

Answer (score -1):

The MySQL Port is closed.

Check the Port with:

```
telnet example.dyndns.org 3306
```

After the Port is open, you have to observe that every MySQL user can have a Host Restriction (localhost by default).